# Get route points on the map

Tags: java, navigation, mapbox

I'm using **mapbox API** and want to get direction from **A** to **B** with `List<Point>` which I can use to draw correct path on the map. But the problem is `DirectionsResponse` returns not enough points, see

[image]

part of line located on the water.
Maybe in the `MapboxDirections` class or another one has `step` method with meters parameter, to get `Point` every 10m.

Here my current code:

```
MapboxDirections directions = MapboxDirections.builder()
                .accessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
                .profile(PROFILE_DRIVING)
                // Brooklyn, NY, USA
                .origin(Point.fromLngLat(-73.947803, 40.677790))
                // Upper West Side, NY, USA
                .destination(Point.fromLngLat(-73.971609, 40.784246))
                .build();

        Response<DirectionsResponse> response = directions.executeCall();
        DirectionsResponse directionsResponse = response.body();
        for (DirectionsRoute route : directionsResponse.routes()) {
            List<Point> decode = PolylineUtils.decode(route.geometry(), PRECISION_6);
            // I need here more points
            for (Point point : decode) {
                System.out.println(point.latitude() + ", " + point.longitude());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have found some solution by using `RouteLeg` with `steps(true)` for `MapboxDirections` but the code looks a little bit poor with a lot of circles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `.overview(DirectionsCriteria.OVERVIEW_FULL)` to get all the points [like in this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/dashed-line-directions-picker/)

Your code would look something like this:

```
MapboxDirections directions = MapboxDirections.builder()
                .accessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN)
                .profile(PROFILE_DRIVING)
                .overview(DirectionsCriteria.OVERVIEW_FULL) /** New line **/
                // Brooklyn, NY, USA
                .origin(Point.fromLngLat(-73.947803, 40.677790))
                // Upper West Side, NY, USA
                .destination(Point.fromLngLat(-73.971609, 40.784246))
                .build();
```